# PHP Dictionary class accepting objects as keys

Tags: php, optimization, performance

I started creating a Dictionary class that accepts objects as there keys:

```
class Dictionary
    implements ArrayAccess
{    
    private $_keys = array();

    private $_values = array();

    public function offsetExists( $key )
    {
        return false !== array_search( $key, $this->_keys, true );
    }

    public function offsetGet( $key )
    {
        if( false === ( $index = array_search( $key, $this->_keys, true ) ) )
        {
            throw new OutOfBoundsException( 'Invalid dictionary key' );
        }

        if( !isset( $this->_values[ $index ] ) )
        {
            throw new LogicException( 'No matching value found for dictionary key' );
        }

        return $this->_values[ $index ];
    }

    public function offsetSet( $key, $value )
    {
        if( false !== ( $index = array_search( $key, $this->_keys, true ) ) )
        {
            $this->_values[ $index ] = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_keys[] = $key;
            $this->_values[] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetUnset( $key )
    {
        if( false === ( $index = array_search( $key, $this->_keys, true ) ) )
        {
            throw new OutOfBoundsException( 'Invalid dictionary key' );
        }

        if( !isset( $this->_values[ $index ] ) )
        {
            throw new LogicException( 'No matching value found for dictionary key' );
        }

        array_splice( $this->_keys, $index, 1 );
        array_splice( $this->_values, $index, 1 );
    }
}
```

It works pretty well for the very elementary test cases I've done so far. However, I'm worried about three things:

1. Can you think of a situation where `$this->_keys` and `$this->_values` will not be synchronized with each other anymore, thus leading to data corruption? I thought maybe there could occur a situation where something might happen between the two `array_splice`s, for instance, in:

   ```
   public function offsetUnset( $key )
   {
       ...

       array_splice( $this->_keys, $index, 1 );
       array_splice( $this->_values, $index, 1 );
   ```

   ... leading to data corruption.
2. I feel `array_search()` might be inefficient, but I specifically don't want to resort to using `spl_object_hash()` as keys (and thereby circumventing the need for an internal *keys* and *values* `array`) as I belief this is not bulletproof, as it doesn't guarantee hash uniqueness for objects at all.
3. I feel `array_splice()` might be inefficient, but I don't want to resort to `unset()` as I feel this could lead to unwieldy internal `array`s keys eventually. I'd like to keep the internal `array`s keys as tightly packed as possible.

Looking forward to your feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I do have to say that you look like you are re-inventing the wheel. You can get all of that with [`SplObjectStorage`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php). Since you're using `OutOfBoundsException`, you're already using the Spl types.

---

To your specific questions:

1. It is hard to think of such a situation, but that doesn't mean that it is inconceivable.
2. While `spl_object_hash` is not guaranteed unique, it is highly likely that you will run out of memory far before encountering a hash collision. As the documents state: *`A string that is unique for each currently existing object and is always the same for each object.`* It is both faster and cheaper than keeping/maintaining your own internal state.
3. Yes, the internal keys will not be quite as ordered in the internal arrays, but it will only make a substantial difference if you actually have a problem keeping the two arrays synced — basically, if you can get #1 to work consistently and without fail, then `unset` will not matter here.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon your implementation and I can really appreciate it - I think this will work well for most people without extreme engineering.

Unfortunately, `spl_object_hash` is just a string representation of the object reference in memory.  For example, if you create two copies of the same array: `array( 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 )`, each object will return a different `spl_object_hash`.

Other languages (such as Java and C#) have a concept of `Equatable` objects.  `Equatable` objects do 2 things:

1. `GetHashCode()`
2. `IsEqual( $other )` - this seems to be what your `array_search()` is doing.

BUT (pay careful attention here) `GetHashCode()` IS NOT COMPLETELY UNIQUE. `GetHashCode()` is 2 different things:

- Consistent!
- FAST!

The idea here is that you can reduce the array passed to `array_search` VERY QUICKLY using `GetHashCode()`, THEN you find the actual match using `array_search()`/`IsEqual()`.

The code might look something like this:

```
$objectiveLookup = new ObjectiveLookup();

//create an association between $obj1 and $val1
$objectiveLookup[ $obj1 ] = $val1;

//Here's what actually happens:
 {
    $hash_code = $obj1->GetHashCode();
    if( !isset( $objectiveLookup->_similarValues[ $hash_code ] ) )
        $objectiveLookup->_similarValues[ $hash_code ] = array();

    //regular array
    $objectiveLookup->_similarValues[ $hash_code ][] = $obj1;

    //this is an SplObjectStorage
    $objectiveLookup->_actualValues[ $obj1 ] = $val1;
 }
```

Then, after thousands, or even millions of objects are in memory, only a fraction of this should be `_similarValues`.

Because of this, finding values should be MUCH faster:

```
//this NEW object should be "IsEqual()" to $obj1
$obj1075383 = new CoolObject();

//get a value
$val1 = $objectiveLookup[ $obj1075383 ];

//Here's what actually happens:
 $hash_code = $obj1075383->GetHashCode();
 if( isset( $objectiveLookup->_similarValues[ $hash_code ] ) )
 {
    $similar_values = $objectiveLookup->_similarValues[ $hash_code ];

    //find the one that IsEqual()
    $matching_index = array_search( $similar_values, $obj1075383 );
    $actual_object_key = $similar_values[ $matching_index ];

    $actual_value = $objectiveLookup->_actualValues[ $actual_object_key ];
    return $actual_value;
 }
```

Overall, nice work fireeyedboy!!